# How to remove an IP address range from analytics?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I don't want company traffic to show up in Sitecore analytics, because it skews goal scores & bounce rates. How do I prevent Sitecore from recording these visits, or how do I at least null-out their value?

Comment: I'm going to redirect this post to another answer, as the answer given and accepted here has serious side effects. Company users will be identified as robots with a 60 second session timeout, and all xDB features and commerce features will stop working for them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that by including the company IP range in 
"**excludedIPAddresses**" section of Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config file (Or by creating a patch config):

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
 <sitecore>
  <analyticsExcludeRobots>
    <excludedIPAddresses>
      10.1.2.3 - 10.1.2.30
    </excludedIPAddresses>
  </analyticsExcludeRobots>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Requests from these IPs will be ignored completely by xDB

Answer (score 3):

You could disable tracking of requests from your servers in the

**\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config**  file in such way:

```
 <!--List of ip addresses of search engines. Requests from following addresses will be ignored by Analytics.
Supported values and formates:
IP address, e.g. 10.2.3.4;
IP range, e.g. 10.1.2.3 - 10.1.2.30;
Subnet, e.g. 10.2.3.*
Use # for comments
See http://iplists.com/ for updates
-->
  <excludedIPAddresses>
  </excludedIPAddresses>
```